# MVC ASP.NET - Redirect to anchor with model state

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

The following code redirects to a view with the anchor and works. However I need to send the model state through for validation and I am not sure how to do that while using a redirect. I want to set the model error to populate the validation summary.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Send(QuoteModel model, string CatchAll)
    {
        try
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "There is something wrong with Foo.");
                return Redirect(Url.RouteUrl(new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"}) + "#quote");
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't do it this way, try to add an additional parameter for your action to determine if the error occurs

```
return Redirect(Url.RouteUrl(new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"}) + "?modelerror=true" + "#quote");
```

and check this url parameter in your action.